# Chrome becomes unresponsive for 30+ seconds after refreshing app (w/ dev tools open)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When I open an app I'm working on in Chrome, for about 30 seconds, all of Chrome's UI elements are unresponsive. The developer tools are completely frozen and the refresh/back buttons act responsive (hover/active states) but they don't function. After about 30 seconds, all of the actions I attempted happen all at once.

My application is not blocking and seems to function completely fine. This isn't an issue in other similar apps I've been running though.

My only guess is that my app is doing something on startup that's causing this, so here's the startup code:

entry.js

```
import "babel-polyfill";
require("./index.html"); // Forces webpack to include our html file

window.onload = () => require("./app");
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Application from "components/application";
import store from "store";
import actions from "store/actions";
import storage from "storage";

require("style/normalize.scss");
require("style/base.scss");

const loadedState = storage.get("state");

if(!!loadedState) {
  store.dispatch({
    type: actions.LOAD_STATE,
    state: loadedState
  });
}

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.time("Saving");
  storage.set("state", store.getState());
  console.timeEnd("Saving");
});

ReactDOM.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById("game-container"));
```

**Edits**:

I just tested the app in Firefox and didn't run into any issues

This issue seems to only appear when I refresh the app while the developer tools are open.

Comment: Do you have a plunkr?

Comment: If you run Chrome's profiler, you should be able to get more info.

Comment: Could the [Chrome Profiler](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoleprofilelabel) be of any use to you?

Comment: When I profile from the start of entry.js to just after `require("./app`)` (inside the callback), the most time consuming entry is `__webpack_require__` which took 224.9ms total

Comment: Could you try again exluding `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`.

Comment: Have you tried turning source maps off?

Comment: @AlexandreKirszenberg That seems to have fixed it. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. I wonder why source maps cause this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try disabling source maps. Source maps are only loaded when the developer tools are open.

I'm not sure why they would cause such a latency. Perhaps the browser freezes while it loads and parses source maps? If so, there's probably something wrong with them.

You could try to use different [source map types](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) to pinpoint the exact cause of your issue.

Comment: I had the same exact issue with webpack dev tools set to devtool: 'source-map' but it seems to be a chrome only issue, working fine with Firefox ie.